# Remove duplicates from sql query for reservation select

Tags: sql

I have the following tables:

- rtable
- reservation

Now `rtable` has the following columns:

- id int primary key
- seats int
- position varchar(10)

And `reservation` has the following columns:

- reservation_id int primary key
- table_id int foreign key(references rtable.id)
- reservation_date date
- start_hour

Now I want to perform the following query:
use restaurant;

```
select id,position,seats from rtable,reservation 
            where (seats >= 6 and position = 'Indoors') 
            and (not exists(select * from reservation where table_id = id) or(
            (exists(select 1 from reservation where table_id = id) and
                (reservation_date != '2017-05-23' or reservation.start_hour != 16))))
```

However this query returns duplicates for rtable.id.
Is there any way to remove these duplicates

Here is an example output:
[image]

Comment: (1) Tag your question with the database you are using.  (2) Explain the logic you are trying to implement (a non-functioning query does not do that).  (3) Provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Please, tag only one RDBMS.

Comment: File mano, giati den xrisimopias katholou to INNER JOIN command ? That itan poly pio apodotiko kai mikro to query sou.

Comment: @P.Soutzikevich dioti den eimai toso kalos ligos kairos pou mathaino sql

Comment: @ManosKounelakis https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp
Otan ksekinisa na mathainw SQL, auto to site me voithise para poly. Exei paradeigmata kai einai katharogrammeno.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using foreign key then why you are not using joins. And why you are checking so much condition, please check this:

```
    SELECT rt.id, rt.position, rt.seats FROM rtable rt LEFT JOIN reservation res
    ON rt.id = res.table_id AND rt.seats >=6 AND rt.position = 'Indoors' AND
    (res.reservation_date != '2017-05-23' AND res.start_hour != 16)
```

Tell me if this solved your issue or give me dataset and condition, I will help you out.

Comment: This at least addresses one of the key problems with the query.

Comment: Here is what I want to do.I get a reservation date,a start hour(which our the reservation starts) from a user and a reservation date.I then want to check which tables have a different reservation_date  than what the user entered or the tables that have the same reservation date but have a different start hour than what the user entered

Comment: what does reservation stores, is it the reservation which are already done for a date at an hour

Comment: @DASH yes it also stores table id and some other user info

Comment: Check the query now, is it solving your purpose, as I changed from inner join to left join and removed where condition and put the condition in joins only

Comment: @DASH there is only one thing bothering me.I have a reservation for '2017-05-23'and start_hour = 16.The query shouldn't return the table with id 24 available however it does.Any ideas?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145783/discussion-between-dash-and-manos-kounelakis).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select distinct id,position,seats from rtable,reservation 
            where (seats >= 6 and position = 'Indoors') 
            and (not exists(select * from reservation where table_id = id) or(
            (exists(select 1 from reservation where table_id = id) and
                (reservation_date != '2017-05-23' or reservation.start_hour != 16))))
```

Comment: This is not the best solution.